# use delete operator to delete .length in an empty function

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(){} 
delete foo.length; 
alert(typeof foo.length);


// result is number
```

Why the above code alert number? Is this a bug?

-Nick

Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete "Throws in strict mode if the property is an own non-configurable property (returns false in non-strict). Returns true in all other cases." http://jsfiddle.net/dDm3B/

Comment: @zerkms new thing learned today. Thanks :)

Comment: All functions in javascript have a length property that equates to the number of arguments that the function is expecting, so you can´t delete.

Comment: @zerkms Actually your fiddle doesn't throw an exception for me (Chrome 64 on macOS), neither it does on Node 9.x. I can delete the length with no error in both strict and non-strict mode, which always changes the length to 0 instead of deleting it. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208272/use-delete-operator-to-delete-length-in-an-empty-function/49228623#49228623) for more details.

Comment: @rsp it was throwing before. Since 2013 it was 4 more ES spec releases.

Comment: @zerkms interesting. I wonder why the strict mode would get less strict with that.

Answer (score 1):

A function object has a built-in property named `.length` that specifies the number of arguments that were defined with the function which is something you can't delete or change its value.

Comment: Actually you **can** delete **and** change the value (at the same time) but you can only change it to zero, and only by using the `delete` operator, not by direct assignment. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208272/use-delete-operator-to-delete-length-in-an-empty-function/49228623#49228623) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The `length` property specifies the number of arguments expected by the function. And it has `property attributes Writable: false, Enumerable: false, Configurable: true`. So you can't delete that. It always returns a number.

Answer (score 0):

### 2018 Update

Actually, it is **even stranger** than your example demonstrates.

Using this code it **seems** that the `foo.length` cannot be changed:

```
function foo() {}
alert(foo.length);        // alerts 0
delete foo.length; 
alert(typeof foo.length); // alerts 'number'
alert(foo.length);        // alerts 0
```

But this is more interesting:

```
function foo(a, b, c) {}
alert(foo.length);        // alerts 3
delete foo.length; 
alert(typeof foo.length); // alerts 'number'
alert(foo.length);        // alerts 0
```

So it's not that your `delete foo.length` doesn't change the value - it does, but it changes it to 0!

It's worth noting that this has no effect in non-strict mode:

```
foo.length = 0;
foo.length++;
```

But both of the above lines will raise an exception in strict mode:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'length' of function 'function foo(a, b, c) {}'

But `delete foo.length` works also in the strict mode, always changing the `foo.length` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

`delete foo.length` does not work because length still exist in function prototype and it is 0.

To change function length or name you can redefine it as writable.

```
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'length', { writable: true, configurable: true });
```

Now you can change length.

Remember if you delete length you'll still have 0 from function prototype. 
You can change it if you want:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(foo, {});
```

Function still be usable.